# FFT for Spectrograms in Python

Tags: python, image, graphics, audio, fft

How would I go about using Python to read the frequency peaks from a WAV PCM file and then be able to generate an image of it, for spectogram analysis?

I'm trying to make a program that allows you to read any audio file, converting it to WAV PCM, and then finding the peaks and frequency cutoffs.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Python's wave library](http://docs.python.org/library/wave.html) will let you import the audio. After that, you can [use numpy to take an FFT](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html) of the audio.

Then, [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/index.html) makes very nice charts and graphs - absolutely comparable to MATLAB.

It's old as dirt, but [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20180122033220/http://www.macdevcenter.com/pub/a/python/2001/01/31/numerically.html) would probably get you started on almost exactly the problem you're describing (article in Python of course).

Comment: matplotlib can also compute the spectrogram directly with the command `specgram`.

Answer (score 16):

Loading WAV files is easy using [audiolab](http://cournape.github.com/audiolab/):

```
from audiolab import wavread
signal, fs, enc = wavread('test.wav')
```

or for reading any general audio format and converting to WAV:

```
from audiolab import Sndfile
sound_file = Sndfile('test.w64', 'r')
signal = wave_file.read_frames(wave_file.nframes)
```

The spectrogram is built into PyLab:

```
from pylab import *
specgram(signal)
```

Specifically, it's part of [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/).  [Here's a better example.](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/specgram_demo.html)

Answer (score 5):

```
from pylab import *
specgram(signal)
```

is the easiest. Also quite handy in this context:

```
subplot
```

But be warned: Matplotlib is very slow but it creates beautiful images. You should not use it for demanding animation, even less when you are dealing with 3D

Answer (score 2):

If you need to convert from PCM format to integers, you'll want to use struct.unpack.