# Recognizing notes within recorded sound - Python

Tags: python, audio

I'm wondering if I can extract a sequence of musical notes from a recorded sound using Python.

It is the first time I'm considering using Python for this.

---

Help would be truly awesome :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you would want to do is take your audio samples, convert them into the frequency domain with a Fast Fourier Transform (FFT), find the most powerful frequency in the sample, and convert that frequency into a note.

See [FFT for Spectrograms in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303307/fft-for-spectrograms-in-python) for pointers to libraries to help with the first two items. See http://80.68.92.234/sigproc.html for some sample code to get you started.

Comment: This tuner seems like it has a great implementation of this: https://github.com/mzucker/python-tuner/blob/master/tuner.py