# Identify audio sample in a file

Tags: java, c++, python, audio, signal-processing

I want to be able to identify an audio sample (that is provided by the user) in a audio file I've got (mp3).

The mp3 file is a radio stream that I've kept for testing purposes, and I have the Pre-roll of the show. I want to identify it in the file and get the timestamp where it's playing in the file.

*Note: The solution can be in any of the following programming languages: Java, Python or C++. I don't know how to analyze the video file and any reference about this subject will help.*

Comment: Are you trying to match what is plainly audible?  Or are you looking for a watermarking solution?  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_watermark_detection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem falls under the category of audio fingerprinting. If you have matched a sample to a song, then you'll certainly know the timestamp where the sample occurs within the song. There is a great paper by the guys behind Shazam that describes their technique: http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Wang03-shazam.pdf  They basically pick out the local maxima in the spectrogram and create a hash based on their relative positions.

Here is a good review on audio fingerprinting algorithms: http://mtg.upf.edu/files/publications/MMSP-2002-pcano.pdf

In any case, you'll likely be working a lot with FFT and spectrograms. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303307/fft-for-spectrograms-in-python) talks about how to do that in Python.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by computing the FFT spectrogram of both the haystack and needle files (so to speak). Then you could try and (fuzzily) match the spectrograms - if you format them as images, you could even use off-the-shelf algorithms for that.

Not sure if that's the canonical or optimal way, but I feel like it should work.