# What's a good way to examine audio with python and split it between high, mid and low pitches for visualizaton?

Tags: python, audio

So, I'm planning on trying out making a light organ with an Arduino and Python, communicating over serial to control the brightness of several LEDs.  The computer will use the microphone or a playing MP3 to generate the data.

I'm not so sure how to handle the audio processing.  What's a good option for python that can take either a playing audio file or microphone data (I'd prefer the microphone), and then split it into different frequency ranges and write the intensity to variables?  Do I need to worry about overtones if I use the microphone?

Comment: See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303307/fft-for-spectrograms-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not committed to using Python, you should also look at using [PureData (PD)](http://puredata.info/) to handle the audio analysis. Interfacing [PD to the Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/PD) is already a solved problem, and there are a lot of pre-existing components that make working with audio easy.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio for links to various Python audio processing packages.

The [audioop package](http://docs.python.org/library/audioop.html) has some basic waveform manipulation functions.

See also:

- [Detect and record a sound with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668442/detect-and-record-a-sound-with-python)
- [Detect & Record Audio in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892199/detect-record-audio-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Portaudio has a Python interface that would let you read data off the microphone.

For the band splitting, you could use something like [a band-pass filter](http://www.musicdsp.org/archive.php?classid=3#92) feeding into an [envelope follower](http://www.musicdsp.org/archive.php?classid=2#97) -- one filter+follower for each frequency band of interest.